# log rotate does not split the file and reduce it

Tags: linux, logrotate, log-rotation

I am trying to implement log rotate in my streaming job. This is my test config file.

```
/home/hadoop/first* {
    daily
    rotate 3
    size 1M
    compress
    delaycompress
}
```

When I try to run logrotate, all that happens is the log file first_run.out is appended with .1 file is not split and zip does not happen to the split file.

Edit:
When I try using -v option, I get this log

```
[hadoop@ip-10-27-90-253 ~]$ sudo logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.conf
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.conf
reading config info for /home/hadoop/first* 

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /home/hadoop/first*  forced from command line (3 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1
  log needs rotating
rotating log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1, log->rotateCount is 3
dateext suffix '-20190411'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 does not exist
renaming /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.3.gz to /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.4.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.3.gz does not exist
renaming /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.gz to /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.3.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.gz does not exist
renaming /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz to /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.2.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz does not exist
renaming /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.gz to /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.gz (rotatecount 3, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.0.gz does not exist
log /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.4.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1 to /home/hadoop/first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is correct.

Maybe your file size is less than 1 MB?

Use the key `-v`, it help you for solve the problem. Eg: `logrotate -v logrotateconfig.file`

---

UPD: your namefile generates recursion for logrotate.

```
first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
first_run.out.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
....
```

Necessary to more precisely specify the filename in the logrotate configuration.

Comment: Thanks for looking, the file size is 3GB

Comment: I will try with -v

Comment: I have posted the log with -v option. Thanks

Comment: thanks I will add the actual file name and try rotating the files